# how to delete a symbol from a image without harming the background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to delete a search symbol button with a grey box on photoshop. But i don't wan't to harm the background (the green frame and the blue image). Can you please show me how or direct me to a site that explain this.

[image: click to see image]

Comment: The solution would depend on your definition of harming. As it seems to be a rather repeating pattern you could just use the copy tool. You can't make it magically make it disappear. You will always have to replace some information with fabricated one.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you can use copy tool in Photoshop. You must be very precise when copy and apply some smoothing on the edges to cover the traces and differences of copy operation.

Other solution is to use healing brush. But nevertheless the background will be changed. On which degree and how this will be visible depend of your experience with Photoshop

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Clone Stamp - but work on a copy as there's as much art as craft in using that tool.

[image]